# Wind Turbine - Current vs Power trend

Tags: power, current, generator, three-phase

I'm looking at wind turbine current - power trends, and there is a phenomenon I need help to explain!

The data I'm analysing is from a 3-phase generator. Below is a scatter plot of current (x axis) against power (y axis).

[image]

Can someone help explain or suggest reasons for the 'tail' at the bottom of the graph?
I don't understand how there can be significant current output, but no power.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: What are the axes - are you sure it is not Voltage across the X-axis?

Comment: You'd see something like this if you applied a short circuit to provide dynamic braking. I'm not saying that's what is happening here, you haven't really told us anything about the wind turbine. If you know anything about its braking systems, add that info to the question.

Comment: Phase issues? Is the power "real power"?

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that at low wind speeds you still get gusts as opposed to a driving wind. It depends on how they define power and measure the current though.

Comment: Definitely current across the x-axis!
The wind turbine uses a hydraulic mechanical brake if that helps?
The power is active power for the whole wind turbine, but the current is from one phase of the three-phase output, the other two phases look exactly the same when plotted against power output!
Many thanks for the suggestions so far, it's a bit puzzling

Comment: Doe the thing switch off the outputs at low speeds.

Comment: What else do you know about the data? Are the points actual operating points for many different times? Do you have power factor data? What are the units of measurement? If PU scale is used, what is the base? What type of generator is it? What type of load is it feeding?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know that much about the actual wind turbine.
Each data point represents an average value over a time interval of 10 minutes.
The data has been normalised between -1 and 1, but for both power and current, -1 represents a real value of 0.
The generator is asynchronous and rated at 2.3MW, but I don't know anything more than that I'm afraid.
The turbine is part of an offshore wind farm.
Could it possibly be caused by 'reactive power at no wind' technology?
see here:
http://www.energy.siemens.com/us/pool/hq/power-generation/renewables/wind-power/NoWind.pdf

Many thanks

Comment: "Reactive power at no wind" seems very likely. The -1 to +1 range for current is peculiar. That seems like an attempt to indicate both current magnitude and power factor on the same axis. I don't know what to make of that. If the plot was published somewhere, there must be other information with it. Who would publish such a thing with no context?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I made the plot, I'm using neural networks to regress the data, and they require the data to be normalised - hence the -1 to +1 range.
It's for my master's thesis, I'm trying to analyse various datasets, but have limited information on the actual turbine itself!

Comment: I restated my comment as an answer, but without understanding your ultimate objective, I am not sure that my answer tells you what you really want to know.

Comment: perhaps if it is a grid connected turbine, the unit is acting as an inductor to balance high capacitance power factor losses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is from a Siemens turbine, it seems likely that a "reactive power at no wind" control scheme is responsible for high current with low or zero power. Even if it is not a Siemens system, some similar scheme is likely responsible assuming there is no problem with the presentation of the data.

However, it is difficult to understand how plotting current vs. power reveals anything useful about the performance of the system.